# Website display incompatibility with smartphones

Tags: css, user-interface

I have a web page which is designed to have a menu bar on top which is a result of an image repeated on the x-axis.

```
width: 900px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-image: url(/images/white-fade-short.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

The menu links are mentioned on with the above mentioned image as the background.This website renders perfectly fine on the desktop. But when loaded on a smartphone the image of the bar is being rendered much more than the actual webpage size and it scrolls up to a particular length . How can I fix this. 
The following css properties also have been set to make it compatible to the smartphone display :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
        img.bg {
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -512px; }
    }
```

Is this code creating a problem in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look at this tutorial http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

It'll help you

Comment: Sorry for the error in the previous details that I mentioned. It was not an image but just a div tag with its color set to grey.
The problem now is that there is a background image to the webpage. and based on its css styles it takes the appropriate size as per the browser on the smartphone. But when I scroll towards the right it still allows me to scroll where the webpage is already turned over and I am just scrolling over the constant background image.Is there any scroll property which when set will stop such phenomenon?